# Cannot get AP list using TL-WN725N wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, vmware

I have a virtual machine in VMWare running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit. I have a TP-Link TL-WN725N wifi usb adapter that I have connected to the virtual machine, and I installed the driver by following [these instructions](http://brilliantlyeasy.com/ubuntu-linux-tl-wn725n-tp-link-version-2-wifi-driver-install/):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
make install
insmod 8188eu.ko
```

After that, I rebooted the machine and now, when I click the connection icon in the status bar, the menu reads *Wi-Fi Networks device not ready*. I ran iwconfig and this was the output:

```
wlxec086b1c2f13  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

ens33     no wireless extensions.
```

In the Network Settings, I can see the wireless adapter is present, but there are no Access Points listed. My research didn't turn up anything at this point, and I'm a little stuck on exactly what problem I'm having, so that's hindering my ability to search out an answer. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, just in case anyone else runs into this:

While waiting for an answer to this question, I happened to need to restart my Windows 10 machine on which this virtual Ubuntu machine is located.

After restarting, and rebooting the virtual machine, as well as disconnecting and reconnecting the USB device from/to the virtual machine, the device worked and found my access point as expected!

Answer (score -1):

you can run this command in your terminal ubuntu

> sudo apt install -y realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms

and then restart your machine